# Composer detected issues in your platform. phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, openssl

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl.

Как избавиться от ошибки при переходе по ссылке http://localhost/i.php?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/pw3IjbzqrBMa-A

Comment: Гм... а перевести не пробовали? там ну очень явно указано, чего нехватает для полного счастья.